# Надстройка модального окна WordPress и ContactForm7

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Использую contact form7 + Easy FancyBox.Подскажите как видоизменить ил где изменять свой код Что бы получилось так же 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пока достиг этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот сам код

```
    <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
   <h4 class="modal-title">Заказать звонок</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="form-group">
<label> 
    [text* your-name class:form-control placeholder " Введите имя*"] </label></div>
 <div class="form-group">
<label> 
    [email* client-name id:my-id class:form-control placeholder " e-mail*"] </label></div>
 <div class="form-group">
<label> 
[textarea* your-message 40x2  class:form-control placeholder "Сообщение*"]</label>
  <p class="help-block" >- поля, помеченные <span class="text-danger">*</span> обязательны для заполнения</p></div></div>
<div class="modal-footer">[submit id:wpcf7-submit1 "Отправить"]
</div></div>
```

Но если взять этот код и прикрутить к кнопке через href"#.." то она запускается как надо, но не отправляет соответственно. Вот этот код

```
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Заказать звонок</h4>
            </div>
                <form class="js-ajax-form form-vertical" data-metrika-target="" data-ga-target="" data-event-metrika="metrika" id="yw1" action="/feedback/feedback/callback/" method="post">
<div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" value="b5fe3e57133655d20beed4accbd3ff450e2954c0" name="ATOM_TOKEN" /></div>                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Ваше имя *" required="required" name="CallbackForm[name]" id="CallbackForm_name" type="text" />                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Ваш телефон *" required="required" name="CallbackForm[phone]" id="CallbackForm_phone" type="tel" />                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Сообщение *" required="required" name="CallbackForm[message]" id="CallbackForm_message"></textarea>                        <p class="help-block">- поля, помеченные <span class="text-danger">*</span> обязательны для заполнения</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
                </div>

                    <input name="CallbackForm[type]" id="CallbackForm_type" type="hidden" value="1" />                    <input name="CallbackForm[page]" id="CallbackForm_page" type="hidden" />
                </form>        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть ли какие-то варианты как решить это?

Comment: ну а какие проблемы - css надо править. Давайте ссылку на сайт, накидаю правки.

Comment: @KAGGDesign вот сайт intellect-media.biz

Comment: занят был, вернулся к вашему вопросу, смотрю - а уже все сделано. Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: @KAGGDesign увы нет, стоит работая версия "для вида" но функционал не работает. Вернуть старую для вашего осмотра?

Comment: @KAGGDesign В header возле кнопки заказать звонок через <a> вывел форму

Answer (score 0):

Надо сделать следующее:

`div.wpcf7` - убрать все стили в style.css

Из этого убрать `display: block;`

```
`<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" style="/* display: block; */" role="alert"></div>`
```

Добавить такие стили в style.css:

```
.fancybox-skin {
    background: transparent;
}

.fancybox-close {
    top: 49px;
    right: 18px;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: а как быть с формой которая находится внизу сайта, там же её фон, загнать в <div> все стили с div.wpcf7 ?

Comment: Нижнюю форму надо обернуть в свой div c отдельным id, чтобы можно было различать эти формы в css.

Comment: а растянуть как форму заполнение что бы было один в один??

Comment: и не пойму где ковырять что бы удалить display: block;

Comment: а что с чем один в один?

Comment: что бы было как на картинке первой. Ну вот я изменил, кое как помогло